# openejb + Tomcat : How to use ejbd protocol?

Tags: java, tomcat, openejb

I have deployed an openEJB.war in a Tomcat container. I have deployed an EJB in the /webapps folder of Tomcat. When I call the ejb via HTTP it works fine :

```
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:8080/openejb/ejb");
```

I would like to use ejbd protocol instead of http but I don't know how to do this. If I replace http://localhost:8080/openejb/ejb by ejbd://localhost:4201/ or ejbd://localhost:8080/ it doesn't work. I think Tomcat doesn't provide any ejbd listener. If I deploy my EJB on openEJB standalone server, it works fine.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For provider url we use

> ejbd://localhost:4201/ejb

Also, you may need to review this page to setup all necessary properties and configuration: http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/embedded-and-remotable.html

Especially, set *openejb.embedded.remotable* to *true*